# Error: Expected undefined to equal in karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Test Case File

```
describe('homeController', function() {
beforeEach(module('moduleInjectionApp'));

var $controller;
var $rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
    $controller = _$controller_('homeController', {'$scope': scope});
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

describe('$scope.ID', function() {
    it('Check the scope object', function() {
        var $scope = {};
        expect($scope.ID).toEqual(5);
    });
  });
});
```

Controller File

```
 angular.module('moduleInjectionApp').controller('homeController', homeController)
 homeController.$inject = ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$location"];
 function homeController($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
     console.log("entered homeController")
     $scope.ID = 5;
     $rootScope.loginObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));
 }
```

Error

```
Error: Expected undefined to equal 5.
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (WebContent/test/home/homeSpec.js:14:31)
        at <Jasmine>
```

> Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.036 secs / 0.012 secs)
>   TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS

Comment: I think scope variable is not accessible from controller file to test case file. Please tell me if i'm doing it in wrong way.

Comment: You declared `var $scope = {}` , how can you expect the `ID` to get created when you initialized it as empty object

Comment: Ok. So now i have changed it like var scope;

Comment: but still getting same error.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know your if it helped. \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
describe('homeController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('moduleInjectionApp'));

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
              $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.ID', function() {
        it('Check the scope object', function() {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('homeController', { $scope: $scope });
            expect($scope.ID).toEqual(5);
        });
    });
});
```

When you declare `var $scope = {};`, you will always get `$scope.ID` as undefined. You need to do

```
var $scope = { ID: 5}
```

Anyways, in unit test, you dont create some values and then `expect` assertions on it. You validate the values which are already defined or have been modified. Here you were trying to declare and then putting `expect` (which will always pass)

Comment: tried this code and getting error                                                                                  ` TypeError: $controller is not a function
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (WebContent/test/home/homeSpec.js:52:20)
            at <Jasmine>
        Error: Expected undefined to equal 5.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (WebContent/test/home/homeSpec.js:56:27)
            at <Jasmine>
Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.02 secs / 0.011 secs)`

Comment: then I passed $controller as argument in beforeEach function, then got error                    ``` Error: Expected undefined to equal 5.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (WebContent/test/home/homeSpec.js:56:27)
            at <Jasmine>
Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.027 secs / 0.014 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS```

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=moduleInjectionApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20)
            at WebContent/test/angular.min.js:7:168
            
            at Object.fb [as injector] (WebContent/test/angular.min.js:46:460)
            at UserContext.WorkFn (WebContent/test/angular-mocks.js:3449:52)
            at <Jasmine>
        Error: Expected undefined to equal 5.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (WebContent/test/home/homeSpec.js:56:27)

Comment: **this is my latest error after adding all dependencies in karma.config.js**

Comment: Error: Expected undefined to equal 5.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (WebContent/test/home/homeSpec.js:55:27)
            at <Jasmine>
Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.05 secs / 0.031 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS

Comment: @ANKITDHORELIYA : can u try updated code and let me know. I have added `scope = $rootScope.$new()` , its been a long time working on `angularjs` so I might be missing something

Comment: I tried updated code, it didn't workout, got same error.

Comment: @ANKITDHORELIYA : Apologies for the delay.Can you try this new code as one last try

Comment: @ANKITDHORELIYA Awesome ! Feel free to upvote as well :)